# LaTeX URL package, how can I display German umlaute in beamerclass

Tags: beamer, symbols, urls

I wanna print the following link ([https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Eidgenössische_Abstimmung_über_die_Verminderung_von_Treibhausgasemissionen_2021.svg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Eidgen%C3%B6ssische_Abstimmung_%C3%BCber_die_Verminderung_von_Treibhausgasemissionen_2021.svg)) in a latex beamer presentation.

Here is my example that leaves out the ö (using another template I got something else than the ö):

```
    \RequirePackage[hyphens]{url}
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref} 

\title{Example Title}
\author{Example Author}
\institute{Example Inst}
\date{\today}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]{Example:}

\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Eidgenössische_Abstimmung_über_die_Verminderung_von_Treibhausgasemissionen_2021.svg}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple workaround: `\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Eidgen%C3%B6ssische_Abstimmung_%C3%BCber_die_Verminderung_von_Treibhausgasemissionen_2021.svg}`

Comment: see also  https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/417154/36296

Comment: I wished there would be a way for me to transform the link this way - however I always see it with ö and ü in my URL address line. And because I have many links I cannot manually change them all.

Comment: Also all the % symbols make my code break and only display the Url until \url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Eidgen"

Comment: They work just fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9ED7.png

Comment: Oh they work, but they show another link (not easy to read for humans)

Comment: You should click the link, not read them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experience no problems with the Umlauts when I (a) compile the document with LuaLaTeX and (b) reformulate your code to employ the `xurl` package instead of the `url` package, to allow the URL string to break anywhere (not just at hyphen characters).

[image]

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{xurl} % allow line breaks at arbitrary points in URL string
\usepackage{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Example}

\url{https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Eidgenössische_Abstimmung_über_die_Verminderung_von_Treibhausgasemissionen_2021.svg}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is weird. Tried it in two different documents (both in overleaf) and never works for me :( (ok didn't use LuaLaTeX correctly)

Comment: you should use a percent encoded url (split with \href). While many pdf viewers can handle url's with umlauts, they are actually not valid in a pdf and so not reliable.

Comment: Okay! If I use \% in the urls it works, just hate changing things manually, as this is very error prone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer - Could you elaborate on the "url's with umlauts ... are ... reliable" comment? E.g., which pdf viewers may have trouble with such url strings? FWIW, Adobe Reader and Acrobat appear to handle the url in question just fine.

Comment: @Mico I don't know the current state, we run a number of tests around 1-2 years ago, and various viewers on mac failed.

Comment: @Mico For example mac Preview.app v. 11.0 fails.